# Django - PostgreSQL set statement_timeout

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-settings

I'm using Django 1.10 and PostgreSQL DB.
I'm trying to figure out whether I can set `statement_timeout` from Django.
Seems like I can't do it the same way as for `connect_timeout` (in `settings.py`):

```
DATABASES[DEFAULT]['OPTIONS'] = {
    'connect_timeout': float(os.getenv('DEFAULT_DB_OPTIONS_TIMEOUT', 5))
}
```

I saw something like this, but I can't find a way to verify it actually works:

```
DATABASES[DEFAULT]['OPTIONS'] = {
    'options': '-d statement_timeout=700'
}
```

I know I can set it directly from the DB like:

```
set statement_timeout=5000
```

but I'm looking for a way to do it from Django.

Answer (score 17):

There is no other "Django" way of doing this. The Django way is to use your `settings.py` like you indicate, except your example is not quite right. It should be:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c statement_timeout=5000',
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The 'OPTIONS' dictionary is for arguments to the database connection string. The list of Postgres arguments can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS). The `options` connection string argument allows you to specify command-line arguments for postgres. The `-c` option is explained [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-OTHER-METHODS).

Note that the timeout is measured in milliseconds, so the `5000` above means 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I use **Django 3.2.16** on **Windows 11** then, I set `'-c statement_timeout=5000'` in `OPTIONS` and `'SET statement_timeout = 5000;'` with `cursor.execute()` in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

from django.db import connection

# ...

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
        # 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    },
    'OPTIONS': {
        'options': '-c statement_timeout=5000' # Here
     }
}

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SET statement_timeout = 5000;') # Here
```

Then, **`test` view** with `cursor.execute('SELECT pg_sleep(10);')` below runs without any errors because `statement_timeout = 5000` in `settings.py` doesn't work in **`test` view**:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.db import connection
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT pg_sleep(10);')
    
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

But, when setting `statement_timeout = 5000` in **`test` view** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.db import connection
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SET statement_timeout = 5000;')
    cursor.execute('SELECT pg_sleep(10);')
    
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

The error below occurs because `statement_timeout = 5000` in **`test` view** works properly. *`cursor.execute('SET statement_timeout = 5000;')` only applies to **`test` view** rather than other views so you need to call `cursor.execute('SET statement_timeout = 5000;')` in each view if you want to apply `cursor.execute('SET statement_timeout = 5000;')` to each view:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: canceling statement due to statement timeout